# Power of one prime never equal to the power of another prime

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove that $2^x$ never equals $3^y$, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: One is even, the other is odd?

Comment: What can you assume?

Comment: @user113387 Are $x$ and $y$ integers? If they are not, then the proofs below don't work. In fact, if they are not, the result is not true (why?)

Answer (score 4):

According to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic every number $x \in\Bbb Z$ has a unique representation of product of prime numbers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

That's not true.  $x=y=0$ is a trivial solution.

Otherwise, the other comments seem to have good answers for $x,y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Because those two numbers have different factors. One is composed of a bunch of 2s. The other is made up of 3s. How could they be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's comment has it right; the idea behind this problem is presumably to prove it without deferring to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Prove that every proper power of $2$, $2^x$ with $x>0$, is even, and that every proper power of $3$, $3^y$ with $y>0$, is odd. Since an odd number cannot equal an even number, you're done.